# Books of collected CD liner/program notes?

Tags: classical-music

I love reading the liner notes and short texts that come inside classical CDs and concert programs. Can you recommend a compilation of these in book form? Either by multiple authors or one, but definitely shorter reading.

Comment: Are liner notes ever collected in a book ?  It's an interesting idea, but I've never heard of this.  A compilation of these from a particular writer or for a particular concert hall or record label could make sense, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to look for compilations of program notes written for performing organizations.  Such as:

- Michael Steinberg  "The Symphony", "The Concerto", "Choral Masterworks"
- Jonathan Kramer  "Listen to the Music"
- David Ewen "The World of Twentieth-Century Music"

There are a few others worth looking for. The Steinberg and Kramer books are still in print, I think, and are available via Amazon, etc.

A. R.